# Using jQuery to create a video switcher

Tags: jquery, video, partial, jwplayer, partial-page-refresh

I've got a design for a video page which has a main video panel which will load the FLV file into JWPlayer when a thumbnail image is clicked.  I think what I'm looking for is a partial page refresh?  What is the best way to achieve this effect?

This is the script I am using to display the video panel:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var s1 = new SWFObject('player.swf','player','682','407','9');
    s1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
    s1.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
    s1.addParam('flashvars','file=Welcome.f4v');
    s1.write('preview');
</script>
```

Comment: Does the player.swf file expose any JavaScript accessible functions like the way YouTube JavaScript API Player does?